# File attachment validation with PHPMailer

Tags: php, forms, validation, phpmailer

I have an html form and I am using PHPMailer to email the form contents. In the form, I have a section for a file attachment. My requirements are that the file must be less than 2mb and it must be a pdf, doc or docx file. When I added in the validation if statement, my form stopped working:

```
if ((isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && filesize($file) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($file), $types)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
}
```

Here is the full PHP script:

```
<?php

require_once('assets/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From = "xxxxx";
$mail->FromName  =  "xxxxx";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxx","xxxxx");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;  

$mail->Subject = "Job form";
$mail->Body="
            First Name: $first_name
            Last Name: $last_name
            Email: $email
            Job: $job";

$maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
$types = array('application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');


if (isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && filesize($file) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($file), $types) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
}


if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo 'Thank you for your feedback.';
}

?>
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="jobform.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone"><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email">
    <select name="job"><br />
        <option>Graphic Design Intern</option>
        <option>ASP.Net Developer</opttion>
        <option>Marketing Coordinator</option>
        <option>Social Media Content Writer</option>
    </select><br />
    <div><h4>Résumé</h4><input type="file" name="fileUpload" /><br /></div>
    <p></p>
    <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that filesize() and mime_type() work the way you are wanting it to.  Similarly to how you have used $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'] and $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], there are values within the $_FILES[] object that provide you with the file size and file type.  See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: yes I am right problem is in parenthesis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're missing a closing parenthesise `)` but look at the following, because your code won't work the way you expect it to...**

I'm not sure that these functions work in the way that you are expecting them to:

```
filesize($file);
mime_content_type($file);
```

These can be used for physical files on the file system, but earlier in your code you assign '$file' to just the string name of your file that you uploaded - not the physical file path like `filesize()` expects!

```
// You assigned the file name, not the file path!!
$file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];
```

When you are doing this, you have assigned the $file variable just the name of the file, not a path to the file itself.

Similarly to how you have used `$_FILES['fileUpload']['name']` and `$_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name']`, there are values within the $_FILES[] object that provide you with the file size and file type once the file has been uploaded:

Check the size:

```
if ($_FILES['fileUpload']['size'] < $maxsize)
{
}
```

Check that it is a PDF:

```
if ($_FILES['fileUpload']['type'] == "application/pdf")
{
}
```

**UPDATE: Attachment not attached**

I think the problem with your file not actually attaching is because you are only providing the temporary name of the file to your `$mail->AddAttachment()` function and not the full path to the file like it expects.

You need to move the file to somewhere where you know where it is first, you can do this using the `move_uploaded_file()` function, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php.

Then when you have the file in a place that you know the path to, provide this path to `$mail->AddAttachment()`.

[This example on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) shows the use of this function to move the file to wherever you want it to be!

Comment: Ok, I got it changed to      if ((isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'] < $maxsize && $_FILES['fileUpload']['type'] == "application/pdf") {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
} Now the form submits no matter what. If the file isn't a pdf than the file isn't attached. I would like for the form not to submit if the file isn't a pdf.

Comment: Check my update, you need to move the file from the temp directory and then provide the FULL PATH to the AddAttachment() function, at the moment you're just providing it with the temp name and not the path to it!

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I figured out how to kill the script. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't wrap your if statement in parenthesis

Comment: That's embarrassing :) That kind of fixed the issue. The form submits but the file is not attached.

Answer (score 0):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND)  on line 2

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && filesize($file) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($file), $types) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
}
```

Perhaps you're missing a few parenthesis here?

Try this instead:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && filesize($file) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($file), $types)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
}
?>
```

Also, I'm not sure mime_content_type may work the way you want to..

** Edit **

I don't think you can get filesize from $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'].

Follow the official W3C example:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

This line:

```
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
```

So, keep in mind that the filesize will be dropped in BYTES, not kilobytes. If you want that in kilobytes, divide it by 1024 like the example above shows.

Comment: @Coulton: hmm...? This is exactly what I wrote, where is the edit? :]

Comment: @Coulton: Got it, sorry, I found out a few minutes after editing that "kilobytes" was not written correctly!

Comment: I added quite a lengthy paragraph and then deleted it as soon as I realised it wasn't my answer. :)

Comment: Oh, interesting.. That was really fast, then! :P